# Magento2 - Change product status programatically depending on View

Tags: magento2, import, command-line

I'm working in a command script to import products to a Magento2 Store. I have more than 10(1 per language) Views for the same Website/Store.

I don't have any problem when a product has to be in all Views of a Store, but i'm trying to enable a product only in one view and not on all Store.

I have seen that in Magento 1.X was a function to do that trick:

```
updateProductStatus($productid, $storeid, $status)
```

but in Magento 2 i can't find the way to do that.

I have also tried looking directly into the database, but without success. Any help on this issue would be helpful because doing manually is impossible, due to the large amount of products.